# Call to a member function on a non-object on modify

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I was trying to update a value but as soon as I try to set something it returns this error

```
Error: Call to a member function setPGuID() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\src\CQ\IntranetBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 19
```

this is my code for the DefaultController and since I copied it from the Symfony2 Docs I have not the slightest id what might be wrong.

```
class DefaultController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $karte = $em->getRepository('CQIntranetBundle:Karte')->findByPGuId('00f8e77c-d8c2-4c7f-8e4a-384cc7689da0');

        if (!$karte) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                    'No product found for id '
            );
        }

        $karte->setPGuID('New product name!');
        $em->flush();
    }

}
```

Also if I do a

```
exit(\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($karte));
```

it returns this

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#497 (9) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(30) "CQ\IntranetBundle\Entity\Karte"
    ["pGuId"]=>
    string(36) "00f8e77c-d8c2-4c7f-8e4a-384cc7689da0"
    ["PBarcode"]=>
    string(13) "3321231140001"
    ["PAnreise"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["PAbreise"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["PMGuId"]=>
    string(36) "07b7c4cf-3441-4339-9b3c-1a581e1271ba"
    ["PDateCreate"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["PDateModify"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
    ["PDateAccess"]=>
    string(8) "DateTime"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

You are using a method that returns an array, no matter how many results it could return.

In your example, it may return 1 result, since the key you are using is unique.

In this case you can use:

```
$karte = $em->getRepository('CQIntranetBundle:Karte')->findByPGuId('00f8e77c-d8c2-4c7f-8e4a-384cc7689da0')[0];
```

which will directly point `$karte` to the first (and only) object into the array.

The same result you will achieve by using a method that returns only one result, as a previous answerer pointed `findOneBy...()`

Answer (score 0):

`$karte` is an array, if you want to set the property on each element of the array, you have to use a loop.

Or if you only want to get one `Karte`, you should use `findOneBy` instead of `findBy`.....